# Nginx only serving PHP files, all other extensions return 'not found'

Tags: php, docker, nginx, server, nginx-config

The current configuration for the nginx server is correctly executing PHP scripts as expected. However, it seems to be encountering issues when it comes to serving other types of files such as CSS and JavaScript files, as well as any other kind of file that is not in the PHP format. As a result, when clients request these files, they are not being returned and a 404 error is being displayed.

Here's the configuration file:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid       /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request"'
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer"'
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    server {

        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;

        sendfile on;


        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000";
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /CRM/index.php?$query_string;
        }

        rewrite ^/CRM/(.*)/v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/(.*)$ /CRM/$1/$2 last;

        location ~ \.php$ {

            fastcgi_pass   crm:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;

            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;

        }
        


    }

}
```

Comment: Your `nginx.conf` looks okay to me. I would say probably either Nginx doesn't have permission to access these files (you could try chmod , or maybe the files don't exist where you say they exist. To give permissions to all users:

`chmod -R a+rwx [your directory]`

Comment: Are your non-PHP files in the PHP container or in the Nginx container? They need to be in the Nginx container.

Comment: @HansKilian they are in separate services in the same container.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example